# Micro controllers need some direction (beginner)

Tags: embedded, arduino, pic

Hello I could not really find the information I was looking for so I decided to ask.  I am looking to get into embedded programming using micro controllers but I am not sure where to start.  The selection of possible choices is huge.  Ultimately my goal is to start a hobby project eventually to develop my own tiny embedded operating system.

With this goal in mind what controller would you recommend?

1. Should allow the use of ASM (I want to learn how the processor works)
2. Has a decent amount of flexibility on what you can create with it. For instance building say a mini computer out of it.
3. Has solid resources for a beginner to learn from.

I was leaning towards Arduino due to popularity but I hear PIC is decent too.

Comment: If you want to build a complete embedded computer with an OS, an ARM board would probably be a better choice.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you comment but ARM is more difficult to wrap you head around from a first timer perspective due to the increased complexity.  Unless there is great documentation on getting started.

Comment: In order of complexity I would say Arduino is the easiest for beginners and more hobby related.  More complicated but still very accessible to beginners are the PICs.  They allow you to build up from a single chip and involve hardware and software learning.  Most complicated would be ARM chips but they are also the most powerful and would only be necessary if you plan on getting into large multitasking or graphic applications. You can do a LOT with Arduino or PIC.

Comment: Would you say arduino/pic would be capable of doing a very simple OS that may only have small amounts of capabilities or maybe for a simple device to do say a 8bit gameboy style game?  These are only ideas as there is tons for me to learn before I get to that point.

Comment: I can't speak as much on the Arduino side but I've worked a lot with PICs and you can start learning on small 8 bit PICs that would plug right into a breadboard for learning.  As you get more comfortable you can work you're way all the way up to 32 bit PICs.  I have a development board with a PIC32 that simultaneously handles HTTP web requests, services a USB port and does file I/O to an SD card so they are quite capable.  If you end up going the PIC route I'd be happy to offer assistance where I can provide it.  See my profile for email address.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The point about Arduino is that it *is not* a microcontroller.  It is an open-hardware/open-source project for board and development tools that make learning and creating embedded systems simple.  To that extent, it probably meets your needs.

Arduino originally used AtmelAVR micro-controllers, though the new [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue) uses an Atmel SAM3X8E ARM Cortex-M3.

To that extent I would recommend an ARM device in any case, so perhaps the Arduino Due is for you, however there are many other board designs for ARM that have a similar ecosystem of support such as [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/), [PandaBoard](http://pandaboard.org/) and the extraordinarily low cost [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/).  The latter already is a "small computer" running Linux, so might be rather too abstracted to make it easy to learn about embedded systems and micro-controllers.

The advantages of using ARM is that it is ubiquitous, ranging in capabilities 10's of MHz and small RAM/Flash parts to application processors running > 1GGz.  ARM do not make chops, they license the architecture to other manufacturers, so many vendors make ARM parts with different proprietary peripheral sets, and for different target applications, so you will always find an ARM part to match your needs.

I would not recommend PIC necessarily, the parts are made by a single vendor, the instruction set is not consistent, there are significant architectural differences between say PIC18, PIC16, PIC18, PIC24 and PIC32 - The latter being in fact entirely different that the preceding PIC architectures. Lower-end PIC devices are not well suited high-level language development.  While this may make learning assembler easy, it does present come compromises when coding in C or C++.  AtmelAVR (used in Arduino) on the other hand has an instruction set specifically designed to support efficient C and C++ compilation.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound fashionable. But Arduino is perfect for beginners. It's IDE makes things just to simple. You can include your assembly or write your own C++. As its a wrapper on top of gcc, giving you the same under workings as the bigger chips. So that you can then exand your skills away from the convenient IDE as you grow into MAKE and Eclipse. Along with allowing a nice path to larger chips.

Pick up on other libraries and tweak them as to get your fingers dirty. And ideas to learn on.

Comment: You make a good point but I would probably go right for the make/console/vim style of development as I am already comfortable with that toolchain.  You do make great points on the flexibility Arduino has.

Comment: Arduino is great, and simple for beginners to get started, but beware that the IDE is hiding a lot of toolchain complexity underneath the simplicity.  It can be quite a leap if you want to get under the covers.